# Specify timestamp column type hint in the creation of a table using SQLAlchemy and Mapped

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, psycopg2

I defined my Post class for the table, but I got the following error. How to include the timestamp in my existing class in order making postgres to register timestamp for each entry?

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi.params import Body  # for storing user sending data
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from random import randrange
import psycopg2
import time
from . import model
from .database import engine, Session, get_db

model.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

import os

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/sqlalchemy")
def test_posts(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return {"status": "success"}

# module.py
from .database import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

# from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from sqlalchemy.types import TIMESTAMP


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    published: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(server_default="true", nullable=False)
    created_at: Mapped[TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)] = mapped_column(
        nullable=False, server_default=text("now()")
)
```

Error:

```
File "/home/shri/Desktop/projects/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 791, in _init_column_for_annotation
    new_sqltype = registry._resolve_type(check_type)
  File "/home/shri/Desktop/projects/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py", line 1268, in _resolve_type
    search = ((pt, pt) for pt in python_type_type.__mro__)
AttributeError: 'TIMESTAMP' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

I would like to know how to correctly define;

```
created_at: Mapped[TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)] = mapped_column(
    nullable=False, server_default=text("now()")
)
```

to make posgres for its automated time registration

Comment: This code _cannot_ throw that error because nothing executes. You need to give more detail

Comment: I added main.py script at the top,

Comment: I ran the command uvicorn app.main:app --reload, after this comman i got the above error

Comment: if you need further details for analysis I will share my github link

Comment: Can you try `pip3 -m install sqlalchemy --upgrade`? I cannot find this specific issue but it's hard to see it as anything other than a bug

Comment: okay I try the above. Actually I am learning fastapi, for this I am using postgres as my database, sqlalchemy as my orm, psycopg2 as my database driver,  Here is my github link for tthe further reference https://github.com/jeelion22/projects/blob/development/fastapi/app/main.py

Comment: I tried after updating sqlalchemy version to 2.0.20 but nothing works, hmm

Answer (score 3):

The type in `Mapped` must be a *Python type*, not a SQLAlchemy type. This declaration ought to work:

```py
from datetime import datetime

created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
    TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=sa.text('now()')
)
```

(note that you don't need to provide *nullable* as it is implied by whether or not the mapped type is optional).

See also the [what's new entry](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#what-s-new-in-sqlalchemy-2-0) for typing in 2.0.

Comment: It works. Thanks buddy. I also tried the following that also worked fine.created_at = mapped_column(
    TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), server_default=sa.text('now()')
)

Comment: I find this such a frustrating answer. `AttributeError: 'TIMESTAMP' object has no attribute '__mro__'` is a _terrible_ indicator that this was the issue all along. I've edited the question title as I think this will come up again; do you think it can be improved to catch more of these issues?

Comment: Apologies, I've re-read my comment but can't edit now. I don't have anything against this answer (I've upvoted it) but in the back of my mind this doesn't add up. "What?!" :P

Comment: Hey @roganjosh I agree the error message is unhelpful - that's why I thought I'd answer rather than just leave a comment.  I'll have a think about whether the Q can be further improved, although having the (fairly unusual) error message present will hopefully be picked up by search engines.

Comment: I'll also see if I can "join the dots" a bit better in the answer, although the docs aren't really explicit on this point, and typing isn't really my thing.

Comment: From my own perspective, I think your answer is fine, it's the question title that counts to make it searchable. This is such confusing behaviour for me

Comment: @roganjosh, the title you edited is well suited:).

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQLAlchemy2.0 DeclarativeBase/mapped syntax, the func import is used to specify timestamp .now() field values.

This SQLAlchemy page provides example code.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html

The following example sets the 'created_at' field as nullable using [Optional] type mapping. Tested using SQLAlchemy -> sqlite.

```
from typing import Optional  
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column  
from sqlalchemy.sql import func  
from datetime import datetime  

class Base(DeclarativeBase):  
    pass


class Book(Base):  
    __tablename__ = "book"  
      
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    author: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    review: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200))
    optional_1: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100), default='A default value here')
    created_at: Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = mapped_column(default=func.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that should work is specifying the `type_` parameter.

```
created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(type_=TIMESTAMP(timezone=True))
```